# How to configure redirects to url with trailing slash in nginx?

Tags: url, nginx, nginx-location, canonical-link

I want to redirect URLs without slash to the path with trailing slash.
So **/some-url** to **/some-url/**

And the rest of the URLs, like

- /some-url.xml
- /some-url?
- /some-url?q=v
- /some-url/

Should stay without redirection.

I found this article https://www.ateamsystems.com/tech-blog/nginx-add-trailing-slash-with-301-redirect-without-if-statements/ in which author suggests to use following rule:

```
location ~ ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ {
   try_files $uri @addslash;
}

location @addslash {
    return 301 $uri/;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't really work. Because url **/some-url?q=v** gets redirected to **/some-url/**

Could you suggest how to change regular expression to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should solve the problem:

```
location / {
    if ($request_uri ~ ^([^.\?]*[^/])$) {
        return 301 $1/;
    }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The query string begins at the `?` and is not part of the normalized URI used when matching `location` and `rewrite` directives. The entire URI is available as the `$request_uri` variable. You could use your regular expression within an `if` block:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^([^.?]*[^/])$ ) { return 301 $1/; }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for more, and [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: this is so weird, it doesn't work for me at all. Url like **showroom.dev/carpage?product_id=1234** still redirects to **showroom.dev/carpage/**. Feels like nginx is misinterpreting regex.

Comment: Ok, seems like in your regex one backslash was missing, it should be **if ($request_uri ~ ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ ) { return 301 $1/; }**

Comment: Escaping a `?` within a character class should not be necessary - I am not sure why you need to escape it on your platform. Also, your regular expression fails the second case in your question as a `?` in the last position matches the second character class.

Comment: True. But actually I don't need the second case. Anyway, thank you Richard.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this without an if statement! This solves all the problems you mentioned (except case #2, and in case #3 it redirects but retains the query string).

```
# 301 try_file for trailing slash
location ~ ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ {
  try_files $uri @addslash;
}

# 301 redirect for trailing slash
location @addslash {
  return 301 $uri/$is_args$args;
}

# Root directory location handler
location / {
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```