# How to configure redirects to url without trailing slash in nginx?

Tags: url, nginx, nginx-location, canonical-link

I want to redirect URLs with slash to the path without trailing slash. So /some-url/ to /some-url for Duplicate Content Issue

And the rest of the URLs, like

```
/some-url.xml
/some-url?
/some-url/?
/some-url?q=v
/some-url/?q=v
/some-url
```

Should stay without redirection. 
i want exactly opposite to following question.
[How to configure redirects to url with trailing slash in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666102/how-to-configure-redirects-to-url-with-trailing-slash-in-nginx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After verifying all the nginx configuration i dint find any else condition and any AND (&&) conditions. finally i did with "set" property in nginx

```
  set $val 0;
  if ($request_method ~ "^GET$"){
      set $val 1;
   }

  if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)/$ ) {
   set $val "${val}1";
  }

  location / {
          if ($val ~ 11) { rewrite ^/(.*)/$ https://$host/$1; }
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider trying inside your server block:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

via: https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/nginx-remove-trailing-slash/

This looks for anything with a request URI starting with a '/' and ending with a slash (the '$' at the end of the search section immediately after the rewrite) and replaces it with the '/' at the beginning and the URI without the ending slash at the end. The final part indicates that it will serve 301 redirects.

Update:
To avoid removing the slash from URIs with GET parameters, please try:

```
if ($query_string != "") {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
}
```

It's generally not recommended to use if statements, but if you were to use a map like this:

```
map $query_string $trailing_slash {
    ""  ""
    default "/";
}
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1$trailing_slash permanent;
```

it would result in infinite redirects for any string with a query, since it would redirect to itself (both source and destination would have the trailing slash in them). Therefore, we need to use a conditional for the rewrite.

Comment: this is not matching for some-url/?,some-url/?q=v . for these urls also redirecting to  some-url? ,some-url?q=v